# A sequence of functions pointwise convergent to $0$ but is not lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Given $f_{i}:(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $B(\mathbb{R})$ denotes Borel sets on the reals.

Construct a sequence of functions such that $\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}(x)=0$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{i}d \mu = \infty$

Attempt:

Let $f_{i} = \frac{1}{i}$. Then $\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i} = 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{i}d \mu = \int \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(x)f_{i}(x)d \mu = \infty$. Hence the limit of the integral is infinite.

Does this argument work or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: The argument works for the problem as stated here. Things become (slightly) more interesting if you also require that $\int_{\mathbb R} f_i\text d\mu <\infty$. It is not hard to adapt your argument to this case.

Comment: @SolubleFish In the more general case I could take $f_{i} = i\mathbb{1}_{(0, \frac{1}{i}]}$?